# I want to add sum for running value on a column but if sequence fails then we have don't have to add

Tags: sql, hadoop, hiveql, impala

I have table like this

```
+----+--------+------+------+
| id | state  | num  | pop  |
+----+--------+------+------+
|  1 | ny     |    1 |  100 |
|  1 | ny     |    2 |  200 |
|  1 | ny     |    3 |  600 |
|  1 | ny     |    6 |  400 |
|  1 | ny     |    7 |  300 |
|  1 | ny     |   14 | 1000 |
|  2 | nj     |    3 |  250 |
+----+--------+------+------+
```

I want output as below

```
+---+----+----+------+------+
| 1 | ny |  1 |  100 |  900 |
| 1 | ny |  2 |  200 |  900 |
| 1 | ny |  3 |  600 |  900 |
| 1 | ny |  6 |  400 |  700 |
| 1 | ny |  7 |  300 |  700 |
| 1 | ny | 14 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2 | nj |  3 |  250 |  250 |
+---+----+----+------+------+
```

So if there is a  seq in num column then we have to add the pop column . So first 3 columns num column has 1,2,3 which is in sequence so we are adding pop column 100+200+600 and displaying as new column.

I tried below code but I am not receiving desired out put

```
select id, state,num, pop,
sum(pop) over (partition by id, state order by num )
from table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subtract a sequence, the values will be constant for the values in a row.  Then you can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(pop) over (partition by state, num - seqnum) as new_population
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by state order by num) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bf2ccfaa1438bb17b6e69c67fda444fd) is a db<>fiddle (using Postgres).

Comment: This is not giving desired output. It is adding up all the values. I want the sum for each sequence .

Comment: @user1024962 . . . I don't know why there was an `order by` in the windowing clause.  Try it now.